# Checking if a Variable has been assigned an Element or a String

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a small library that involves object manipulation, and there will be an input that might be assigned an ID of an element (which will then use `document.getElementById`), or something like `document.getElementBy`... and whatever goes here.

Does anyone know how to determine if its a string or an HTML Element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof) should work:

```
typeof variable == "string"
```

Answer (score 2):

[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof)

http://jsfiddle.net/zeF4J/